# Energy loss through gravity and the law of conservation of energy

Tags: gravity, forces, energy-conservation

Since every object exerts a force of gravity on all objects around it, how can it lose so much energy at all times without ever stopping? If an object always loses energy from gravity, how does it constantly keep the same force of gravity at all times?

Answer (score 1):

Exerting force does not necessarily lead to energy changes.

Comment: Yes, energy changes are always going to either be changes in kinetic energy, which require either change in speed or change in the heat contained in a body (due to a change in the average speed of the molecules in it), *or* changes in potential energy, which in the case of gravitational potential energy would require a change in distance between gravitating bodies (like a change in height, which is distance from the Earth).